# Android Bluetooth BLE disconnect after 30 seconds

Tags: android, bluetooth

I should connect to the Wurth Proteus-II bluetooth device but I still have the same problem with other apps as well. I tried both with the nRF Connect app and with the official Wurth app but with both it disconnects after 30 seconds.
After connecting I use this:

```
private static boolean setCharacteristicNotification(
            BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled) {
        if (bluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w("TAG", "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return false;
        }

        bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

        try {
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(UUIDDes));
            if (descriptor != null) {
                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                return (bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor));
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG", "descriptor is null");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

after this I see the led flash 2 times on my device which indicates the successful connection but after 30 seconds it disconnects.
On nRF connect App I also tried to send him commands and the device responds correctly but after 30 seconds the connection drops, what could be the problem?

Comment: What's the status code for the disconnection? Is it 19 (remote device terminated the connection) or 22 (local device terminated the connection)? If 22, it probably means it didn't respond to some request. If 19, you need to ask the manufacturer of the remote device why they disconnect.

Comment: @Emil this is the error onClientConnectionState() - status=59

Comment: "The Unacceptable Connection Parameters error code indicates that the remote device either terminated the connection or rejected a request because of one or more unacceptable connection parameters." Android uses some particular connection parameters during service discovery. Maybe it's those that your device doesn't like. Tough luck. Tell the developer of the peripheral that they should be more acceptive.